# Is ext4 still prone to data loss in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: ext4, data-loss

When ext4 was relatively new, it was said you can easily lose data during a power failure. Unfortunately, you sometimes cannot shut down your computer properly, and then you have to cause a power failure deliberately. There is [an article](http://www.pointsoftware.ch/en/4-ext4-vs-ext3-filesystem-and-why-delayed-allocation-is-bad/) that says, you should mount an ext4 file system with the `nodelalloc` option to prevent such data loss. However, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS does not use this option by default. Has the ext4 implementation been modified such that such data loss cannot occur anymore, or is the default configuration of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS unsafe?

Comment: The linked article is not available saying "This web page cannot be displayed because the configured PHP version is no longer supported and no extension has been requested. "...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every file system is prone to data loss, so the answer is "Yes".

It is everyone's personal choice to pick the file system that s/he feels meets her/his requirements. The default ext4 for Ubuntu was not chosen because it is free from data loss (or "the best" in any other way), but because it adequately meets the requirements of a large group of users.

Ext4 is fine for that large group.  Users with additional requirements have the option of changing the default - and then discuss the advantages of their choice with others who are into that sort of thing ;-).

Comment: The article I have linked to discusses in Section 4.3 a particular problem with ext4. In particular, it says, “In conclusion, ext4 with default options guarantees after a crash only the atomicity and consistency of the filesystem changes (all metadata) with a maximum loss of 5 seconds on metadata changes. The data changes may suffer a loss of 30–150 seconds and in the majority of cases all changed files in this window will be completely wiped with zero bytes! The atomicity of file changes is not working anymore with the rename-idiom.” Is this problem still present in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: @WolfgangJeltsch losses in that range (30-150 seconds) could equally be incurred due to write caching parameters set on the hard disc, kernel parameters settings for the write buffers, etc. Ext4 would be just one player among other factors. The fact that `nodelalloc` is not enabled by default (but is still available as a mount option) suggests that it was not considered (or found to be, empirically) relevant for the average Ubuntu desktop or server.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ext4 by preference on my Linux partitions for about five years (MEPIS 11 and Kubuntu 14.04.*), and never had issues with data loss -- despite several power failures per year, and a laptop that likes to lock up on the screen saver from time to time.  I did have data loss and file corruption on an antiX system where I ran ext2 (thinking a non-journaling system would extend the life of the 16 GB Compact Flash card I had used to replace a 4 GB hard disk), but after converting that system to ext4, even that one never gave me trouble.

It's my understanding that the journaling of ext3 and ext4 works to either prevent file damage in an unexpected shutdown, or allows the OS to recover any data that's become disconnected during the next startup.